# Need help tuning a complicated query

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, performance-tuning

I've inherited a rather complex stored procedure that is causing timeouts in our Production environment.  I've used SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to help me look at some of the issues.  I've identified a few but I'm having a hard time coming up with optimizations that can be made. We are using SQL Server 2019 with `COMPATIBILITY_VERSION = 150`.

This sproc returns data to a web client for via an API call so the performance of the page load is very important. This stored procedure has been identified as the bottleneck thru several app profiling sessions.

Here are some of the issues identified:

1. Timeouts in PROD where we have 4+ millions of rows of data (ActualElapsedms = 11499)
2. Estimated Subtree Cost is a whopping 187.74 (our next slowest sproc has a subtree cost of .653)
3. Parts of the query plan show Residual I/O (surprisingly one of them is even an Index Seek)
4. There is a `tempdb` spill data warning
5. Logical Reads is almost 128k
6. Sentry shows 3 Missing JOIN Predicates on the `INSERT INTO @ValidRows....` but I don't know how to identify them.

There are indexes on the tables involved and from what I can see they appear to be sufficient. However, I see a number of Index Scans being called out in the Plan as problem areas (yellow highlight)

Here is a link to the Actual Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1TN4NOS9

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DailyNotePublishedContentView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT
    T.Id AS DailyNoteContentId,
    T.DateModified,
    T.ModifiedBy,
    T.Region,
    T.DateAdded,
    T.CreatedBy,
    V.Id AS VersionId,
    V.DateAdded AS VersionDateAdded,
    V.CreatedBy as VersionCreatedBy,
    V.ContentType,
    V.DateDue,
    V.IsPrivate,
    V.ProjectId,
    V.PublishDate,
    V.AuthorTeamId,
    V.ContactEmail,
    V.Content,
    V.ContentText,
    V.Summary,
    V.SummaryText,
    V.AllowAddendums,
    StoreTeamsList = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),STA.[Name]), ', ')     
        FROM
            [dbo].[DailyNoteContentStoreTeam] (NOLOCK) ST
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Audiences] (NOLOCK) STA ON STA.Id = ST.AudienceId AND STA.IsActive = 1
        WHERE
            ST.DailyNoteContentVersionId = V.Id 
    ),  
    AssignedToList = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),TAA.[Name]), ', ')     
        FROM
            [dbo].[DailyNoteContentAssignedTo] (NOLOCK) TA
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Audiences] (NOLOCK) TAA ON TAA.Id = TA.AudienceId AND TAA.IsActive = 1
        WHERE
            TA.DailyNoteContentVersionId = V.Id         
    )       
FROM
    [dbo].[DailyNoteContent] (NOLOCK) T 
    CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1
                V.Id,
                V.DateAdded,
                V.CreatedBy,
                V.ContentType,
                V.DateDue,
                V.IsPrivate,
                V.ProjectId,
                V.PublishDate,
                V.AuthorTeamId,
                V.ContactEmail,
                V.Content,
                V.ContentText,
                V.Summary,
                V.SummaryText,
                V.AllowAddendums
            FROM
                [dbo].[DailyNoteContentVersion] (NOLOCK) V
            WHERE
                V.DailyNoteContentId = T.Id
            ORDER BY V.DateAdded DESC
        ) AS V
    -- Only inlcude published content
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DailyNotePublishStatus] (NOLOCK) PS ON 
        PS.PublishDate = V.PublishDate 
        AND PS.RegionId = T.Region 
        AND PS.IsReadyToPublish = 1
        -- TODO: Account for user defined publish time/timezones?
        AND PS.PublishDate <= CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
WHERE
    T.IsDeleted = 0 
WITH CHECK OPTION;

GO
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135749/discussion-between-dave-black-and-andrew-sayer).

Answer (score 8):

9.308s of the 11.5s elapsed time for your query is consumed by the batch mode hash match right join at node 7 in the provided execution plan. This is unexpected for ~4M build-side and ~13k probe-side rows.

The most likely explanation is the ~30k hash spilled pages to *tempdb*, but even this is unreasonable performance. It seems most likely your *tempdb* is under severe pressure, due to either to insufficient raw I/O performance or allocation contention. You should look into that and fix it if you can. It may be the system is making excessive use of table variables and other things that put pressure on *tempdb*.

That said, the spill ought to be avoidable. I notice from the plan you have memory grant feedback disabled, perhaps for good reason. Still, one underlying cause is the inaccurate cardinality estimation from the table variables.

You are making use of [table variable deferred compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing#table-variable-deferred-compilation), but that only helps so much. Initial estimates can easily prove to be out of date or otherwise unrepresentative on subsequent executions of the plan. For example, the estimate on @UserAudiencesTable is 20 rows, but 157 are encountered at runtime.

The cross joins (leading to the missing join predicate warnings) are introduced by the optimizer as it seeks to implement the complicated correlated `OR EXISTS` clauses in the section of the query commented with "Optional: Targeted to user location". The inaccurate cardinality estimates are multiplied through these joins, leading to the spill at the hash join.

This brings me to another issue. The query is of a kind frequently referred to as a "kitchen sink" query - it attempts to accommodate many queries with optional components. The presence of `IS [NOT] NULL OR` expressions is the giveaway here. These make life very difficult for cardinality estimation, and hence final plan quality. Throw in a complex view as part of a query with multiple outer joins, applies, and subqueries, and you have a recipe for poor outcomes.

As a quick experiment, I suggest you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the `INSERT` query. This will give the optimizer some scope to simplify things by embedding the runtime values of variables, and use the actual runtime cardinality of the table variables. Compilation time for the statement is not excessive at 318ms compared with execution time, so you might even find this is a 'good enough' solution for now.

The results of using the recompile hint might at least inform the general direction of future improvements you might choose to make, such as generating only the needed parts of the statement using carefully-written dynamic SQL.

You might also look into using temporary tables instead of table variables here, if statistics on those tables might benefit plan quality. Better indexes (replacing or adding to the existing clustered index) might also be worth considering. Providing additional indexes can make it easier for the optimizer to find an obviously efficient plan.

Residual I/O is not necessarily a problem, but it does indicate that a predicate has to be applied after the seeking operation to further qualify rows. This may or may not be avoidable with better indexing.

In summary, tuning this query and workload would be a consulting engagement, and there is not nearly enough information in the question to venture beyond the general commentary above, but it might give you some ideas to pursue.

Ultimately, using table variables and writing complex queries over complex views are not especially compatible with reliably good execution plans and system performance.

You should also consider patching your instance beyond the current CU8 (October 2020 vintage). I can't promise that will improve performance here, but you might benefit from some of the improvements and fixes released in the past 18 months or so.

Oh and try to remove those `NOLOCK` hints, they're not magic performance-enhancers. If you can live with reading dirty data etc. run your workload at READ UNCOMMITTED isolation.

Definitely look into your *tempdb* situation as well.

Answer (score 3):

-Edit-

Unfortunately, this analysis was given based on an actual execution plan which was not representative of your real situation. My initial comments (which seem to have been removed) about your use of table variables look like the best place to start here. In the execution plan this analysis was based on, your table variables had 1 row each, which is how the optimizer would treat them. Your latest edit shows that really these table variables will have plenty of data in.

-- Edit 2

These two execution plans were critically different in the way they were using the table variables. The faster plan was looping lookups of it for the existence checks after doing all the big work. The slower plan was cross joining the tables together in a few ways to allow it to filter the existence checks with a hash join. Importantly, so long as these two plans are from the same DB (or from a DB with the same constraints, data types etc) then the plan you managed to get before will still be legal. Things like `optimize for` [hint](https://sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-using-optimize-for-query-hint/) could help you get back there (the values the faster plan was compiled for are available in the plan xml). Alternatively, you can rewrite those exists checks as `left join` with `not null` filters on the join columns, this will make it easier to hint.

```
INSERT INTO @ValidRows (Id) SELECT DISTINCT 
        V.DailyNoteContentId
    FROM
        [dbo].[DailyNotePublishedContentView] (NOLOCK) V        
        LEFT JOIN DailyNoteContentLocation (NOLOCK) L ON L.DailyNoteContentVersionId = V.VersionId
        LEFT JOIN Audiences (NOLOCK) LA ON LA.Id = L.AudienceId     
        LEFT JOIN DailyNoteContentStoreTeam (NOLOCK) ST ON ST.DailyNoteContentVersionId = V.VersionId
        LEFT JOIN DailyNoteContentAssignedTo (NOLOCK) AST ON AST.DailyNoteContentVersionId = V.VersionId
        LEFT JOIN (select distinct uat.id from @UserAudiencesTable uat) uat1 on uat1.id = L.AudienceId
        LEFT JOIN (select distinct uat.id from @UserAudiencesTable uat) uat2 on uat2.id = ST.AudienceId
        LEFT JOIN (select distinct uat.id from @UserAudiencesTable uat) uat3 on uat3.id = AST.AudienceId
        LEFT JOIN (select distinct lat.id from @LocationAudiencesTable lat) lat on lat.id = L.AudienceId
        OUTER APPLY(
            SELECT TOP 1
                TR.IsCompleted,
                TR.DateCompleted
            FROM
                DailyNoteContentTaskResult (NOLOCK) TR              
            WHERE
                TR.DailyNoteContentId = V.DailyNoteContentId
                AND TR.LocationId = @LocationId
            ORDER BY V.DateAdded DESC
        ) AS TR
    WHERE
        V.ContentType = 'todo' AND 
        -- Requried: Return region content plus global content (for addendum or readonly viewing)
        (V.Region = @Region OR (V.Region = 'CE' AND (LA.Regions IS NULL OR CHARINDEX(@Region, LA.Regions) > 0))) AND 
        -- Optional: Filter by project
        (@ProjectId IS NULL OR V.ProjectId = @ProjectId) AND 
        -- Optional: Include only store team matches (if not focus of the week)
        (@StoreTeamId IS NULL OR @IncludeAllTeams = 1 OR ST.AudienceId = @StoreTeamId) AND 
        -- Requried: Only show content targeted to current location audiences unless focus of the week
        (@LocationAudiencesJson IS NULL OR lat.id is not null ) AND 
        -- Targeting        
        (           
            -- Don't check targeting if store team id is provided
            (V.IsPrivate = 0 AND (@StoreTeamId IS NOT NULL OR @IncludeAllTeams = 1)) OR  
            -- If private and inlcude private is checked only apply when viewing by store team
            -- personalized view will show private by default due to targeting checks if the user
            -- should see the content
            (V.IsPrivate = 1 AND (@StoreTeamId IS NOT NULL OR @IncludeAllTeams = 1) AND @IncludePrivateContent = 1) OR 
            (               
                -- Optional: Targeted to user location
                (uat1.id is not null OR lat.id is not null) AND  
                -- Optional: Targeted to user store team
                uat2.id is not null AND 
                -- Optional: Targed to user assigned to audience
                uat3.id is not null
            )
        ) AND   
        -- Filter by start/end dates
        (           
            -- To Do            
            V.PublishDate <= @WorkingDate AND   
            -- Past the due date
            CONVERT(DATE, V.DateDue) < @WorkingDate AND 
            -- Pending/Overdue (return if past due date and not completed)
            (TR.IsCompleted IS NULL OR TR.IsCompleted = 0)          
        )
```

-- Original

As mentioned in the comments, your IO is mainly from the nested loops of the `DailyNoteContentVersion` index. Looking at your view definition this is from the `cross apply` query you are doing. We can see that your main driving filters aren't being applied until all this work has already been done.

I see two options:

1. Make it so that it can drive from these existence checks and the other `OR`ed condtions. This would be a bit tricky but manually expanding out the query with `union all`s might do the trick
2. Make the rest of the query able to use bulky operations to speed that up instead of the nested loops it's currently doing.

I think 2) would be easier. You can modify the `DailyNotePublishedContentView` view so that it does the join to the `TOP 1 DailyNoteContentVersion` row in a batchier way:

```
JOIN (SELECT V.Id,
             V.DailyNoteContentId,
             V.DateAdded,
             V.CreatedBy,
             V.ContentType,
             V.DateDue,
             V.IsPrivate,
             V.ProjectId,
             V.PublishDate,
             V.AuthorTeamId,
             V.ContactEmail,
             V.Content,
             V.ContentText,
             V.Summary,
             V.SummaryText,
             V.AllowAddendums,
             row_number() over (partition by V.DailyNoteContentId order by V.DateAdded DESC) rn
        FROM
            [dbo].[DailyNoteContentVersion] (NOLOCK) V
    ) AS V
    ON V.DailyNoteContentId = T.Id
   AND V.rn = 1
```

This would replace your `CROSS APPLY`